# How to get my rotation animated rss feed working correctly with jQuery and php?

Tags: php, jquery, animation

I am a graphic design student and this is my first question here. For one of my projects I am trying to make a graphic rotation display for an rss feed. Ten lines of newsfeeds make up a star that rotates clockwise. I am a beginner when it comes to jQuery, Ajax and PHP. My teacher has helped me along, but due to limited time he hasn't been able to explain everything to me in such a way that I understand everything. So I am stuck with a piece of coding that more or less does what I want it to do except rotate the way I intended.

[image: This is an image of what it looks like]

It is supposed to rotate clockwise and continue rotating while it refreshes, but somehow after a couple of seconds separate lines start to rotate counterclockwise. I think it has to do with the set rotation angles, but I am clueless on how to solve it.

This is my code so far: 
index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>News</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
        <script src="zepto.js"></script>
        <script src="zepto.fx.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
}

div {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.line {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.block {
    text-align: center;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
```

This is then the JQuery/Zepto section: 
script.js

```
var rotations = [0,18,36,54,72,90,108,126,144,162];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "ajax.php", function(r) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(r);
        console.log(json);
        for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var block = $('<div class="block"></div>');
            $("body").append(block);
            for(var j = 0; j < json[i]["lines"].length; j++) {
                var line = $('<div class="line">'+json[i]["lines"][j]+'</div>');
                block.append(line);
                rotateLine(line);
            }
        };
    });

});
function rotateLine(obj) {
    i = obj.index();
    rotation = obj.attr("rotation");
    if(!rotation) rotation = rotations[i];
    else rotation = rotation*1+180;
    if(rotation > 360) rotation -= 360;
    obj.attr("rotation", rotation);
    console.log(rotation);
    obj.animate({
        'rotateZ': rotation+'deg'
    }, 
        10000,
        'linear', function() { rotateLine(obj)});
}
```

And final section:
ajax.php

```
     <?php
    $f = file_get_contents("http://news.google.nl/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=nl_nl&hl=nl&output=rss");//http://news.google.nl/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=nl_nl&hl=nl&output=rss");
    $news = new SimpleXMLElement($f);
    $result = array();
    for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        preg_match("/story\?ncl=([^&]*)/",$news->channel->item[$i]->description, $matches);
        //var_dump( $matches);      
        $g = file_get_contents('http://news.google.nl/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=nl_nl&hl=nl&output=rss&ncl='.$matches[1]);
        $item = new SimpleXMLElement($g);
        //echo '<div class="line">'.( $news->channel->item[$i]->title).' - <a href="http://news.google.nl/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=nl_nl&hl=nl&output=rss&ncl='.$matches[1].'">link</a><br />';
        $resultitem = array();
        $resultitem["title"] = ( $news->channel->item[$i]->title).' - '.$news->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
        $resultitem["lines"] = array();
        for($j=0; $j < 10; $j++) {
            $resultitem["lines"][] = ($item->channel->item[$j]->title).' - '.$item->channel->item[$j]->pubDate;
        }
        $result[] = $resultitem;

    }
    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

My apologies for the amount of text, but as I said, I am a beginner that has been given a lot of code by his teacher to work with. Any help will be much appreciated! 
Best regards, Eelke (NL)

Comment: If you comment out the line: `if(rotation > 360) rotation -= 360;` does that make it do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried and it works better already, except that over time (let's say about a minute or so) individual lines start rotating at a higher speed than the rest of the lines. When the faster line has made a full circle then it connects to the speed of the other lines again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use css3? No need for javascript then

see my jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8mhrmoh4/1/

> ```
> .spinner {
>   vertical-align: middle;
>   -moz-animation: 2s rotate infinite linear;
>   -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
>   -webkit-animation: 2s rotate infinite linear;
>   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
> }
> @-moz-keyframes rotate {
>   0 {
>     -moz-transform: rotate(0);
>   }
>   100% {
>     -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
>   }
> }
> @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
>   0% {
>     -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
>   }
>   100% {
>     -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank your for your advice. I understand your code. However it is in the javascript/jQuery where the div classes are generated out of the rss feed. So when I were to use your css3 code (which looks very understandable) then I would no longer have the divs I could apply the css rotation to? Or am I missing something in my reasoning?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean but  you can insert elements into your DOM and the css rules will apply to them. Have a look at my modified example https://jsfiddle.net/8mhrmoh4/3/ . The spinner element could also come from your ajax method